# Exception loading model for varian [block] for blockstate [state] MissingVariantException

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to add a new block to the game with different textures on each side and it throws an error Exception loading model for variant.

```
blockstates/c_furnace.json 
{
    "variant": {
        "burn=false,facing=north": {
            "model": "compressedcobble_mod:c_furnace/c_furnace"
        },
        "burn=false,facing=east": {
            "model": "compressedcobble_mod:c_furnace/c_furnace",
            "y": 90
        },
        "burn=false,facing=south": {
            "model": "compressedcobble_mod:c_furnace/c_furnace",
            "y": 180
        },
        "burn=false,facing=west": {
            "model": "compressedcobble_mod:c_furnace/c_furnace",
            "y": 270
        },
        "burn=true,facing=north": {
            "model": "compressedcobble_mod:c_furnace/lit_c_furnace"
        },
        "burn=true,facing=east": {
            "model": "compressedcobble_mod:c_furnace/lit_c_furnace",
            "y": 90
        },
        "burn=true,facing=south": {
            "model": "compressedcobble_mod:c_furnace/lit_c_furnace",
            "y": 180
        },
        "burn=true,facing=west": {
            "model": "compressedcobble_mod:c_furnace/lit_c_furnace",
            "y": 270
        }
    }
}
```

```
blocks/c_furnace
{
    "parent": "block/orientable",
    "textures": {
        "particle": "compressedcobble_mod:blocks/c_furnace/furnace_front",
        "up": "compressedcobble_mod:blocks/c_furnace/furnace_top",
        "down": "compressedcobble_mod:blocks/c_furnace/furnace_top",
        "north": "compressedcobble_mod:blocks/c_furnace/furnace_front",
        "east": "compressedcobble_mod:blocks/c_furnace/furnace_side",
        "south": "compressedcobble_mod:blocks/c_furnace/furnace_side",
        "west": "compressedcobble_mod:blocks/c_furnace/furnace_side"
    }
}
```

```
CompressedFurnace.java 
public class CompressedFurnace extends BlockBase implements ITileEntityProvider {

    public static final PropertyDirection FACING = BlockHorizontal.FACING;
    public static final PropertyBool BURNING = PropertyBool.create("burn");

    public CompressedFurnace(String name, Material mat) 
    {
        super(name, mat);
        setUnlocalizedName(name);
        setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.BUILDING_BLOCKS);

        setDefaultState(blockState.getBaseState().withProperty(BURNING, false).withProperty(FACING, EnumFacing.NORTH));
    }

    @Override
    public Item getItemDropped(IBlockState state, Random rand, int fortune)
    {
        return Item.getItemFromBlock(ModBlocks.B_FURNACE);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemStack getItem(World worldIn, BlockPos pos, IBlockState state)
    {
        return new ItemStack(ModBlocks.B_FURNACE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onBlockActivated(World w, BlockPos pos, IBlockState state, EntityPlayer p, EnumHand hand, EnumFacing facing, float hitX, float hitY, float hitZ)
    {
        if(!w.isRemote)
        {
            p.openGui(Main.instance, Reference.GUI_C_FURNACE, w, pos.getX(), pos.getY(), pos.getZ());
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBlockAdded(World w, BlockPos pos, IBlockState state)
    {
        if(!w.isRemote)
        {
            IBlockState north = w.getBlockState(pos.north());
            IBlockState south = w.getBlockState(pos.south());
            IBlockState east = w.getBlockState(pos.east());
            IBlockState west = w.getBlockState(pos.west());

            EnumFacing face = (EnumFacing)state.getValue(FACING);

            if(face == EnumFacing.NORTH && north.isFullBlock() && !south.isFullBlock()) face = EnumFacing.SOUTH;
            else if(face == EnumFacing.SOUTH && south.isFullBlock() && !north.isFullBlock()) face = EnumFacing.NORTH;
            else if(face == EnumFacing.EAST && east.isFullBlock() && !west.isFullBlock()) face = EnumFacing.WEST;
            else if(face == EnumFacing.WEST && west.isFullBlock() && !east.isFullBlock()) face = EnumFacing.EAST;
            w.setBlockState(pos,  state.withProperty(FACING, face), 2);

        }
    }

    public static void setState(boolean active, World w, BlockPos pos)
    {
        IBlockState state = w.getBlockState(pos);
        TileEntity tile = w.getTileEntity(pos);
        if(active)
            w.setBlockState(pos, ModBlocks.B_FURNACE.getDefaultState().withProperty(FACING, state.getValue(FACING)).withProperty(BURNING, true), 3);
        else
            w.setBlockState(pos, ModBlocks.B_FURNACE.getDefaultState().withProperty(FACING, state.getValue(FACING)).withProperty(BURNING, false), 3);
        if(tile != null)
        {
            tile.validate();
            w.setTileEntity(pos, tile);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TileEntity createNewTileEntity(World worldIn, int meta) 
    {
        return new TileEntityC_Furnace();
    }

    @Override
    public IBlockState getStateForPlacement(World w, BlockPos pos, EnumFacing facing, float hitX, float hitY, float hitZ, int meta, EntityLivingBase placer, EnumHand hand)
    {
        return this.getDefaultState().withProperty(FACING, placer.getHorizontalFacing().getOpposite());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBlockPlacedBy(World w, BlockPos pos, IBlockState state, EntityLivingBase placer, ItemStack stack)
    {
        w.setBlockState(pos, this.getDefaultState().withProperty(FACING, placer.getHorizontalFacing().getOpposite()), 2);
    }

    @Override
    public EnumBlockRenderType getRenderType(IBlockState state)
    {
        return EnumBlockRenderType.MODEL;
    }

    @Override
    public IBlockState withRotation(IBlockState state, Rotation rot)
    {
        return state.withProperty(FACING, rot.rotate((EnumFacing)state.getValue(FACING)));
    }

    @Override
    public IBlockState withMirror(IBlockState state, Mirror mirror)
    {
        return state.withRotation(mirror.toRotation((EnumFacing)state.getValue(FACING)));
    }

    @Override
    protected BlockStateContainer createBlockState()
    {
        return new BlockStateContainer(this, new IProperty[] {BURNING,FACING});
    }

    @Override
    public IBlockState getStateFromMeta(int meta)
    {
        EnumFacing facing = EnumFacing.getFront(meta);
        if(facing.getAxis() == EnumFacing.Axis.Y) facing = EnumFacing.NORTH;
            return this.getDefaultState().withProperty(FACING, facing);
    }

    @Override
    public int getMetaFromState(IBlockState state)
    {
        return ((EnumFacing)state.getValue(FACING)).getIndex();
    }

    @Override
    public void breakBlock(World w, BlockPos pos, IBlockState state)
    {
        TileEntityC_Furnace TE = (TileEntityC_Furnace) w.getTileEntity(pos);
        InventoryHelper.dropInventoryItems(w, pos, TE);
        super.breakBlock(w, pos, state);
    }
}
```

```
[04:12:11] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: Exception loading model for variant compressedcobble_mod:c_furnace#burn=false,facing=west for blockstate "compressedcobble_mod:c_furnace[burn=false,facing=west]"
net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry$LoaderException: Exception loading model compressedcobble_mod:c_furnace#burn=false,facing=west with loader VariantLoader.INSTANCE, skipping
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:161) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.registerVariant(ModelLoader.java:235) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadBlock(ModelBakery.java:153) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.loadBlocks(ModelLoader.java:223) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.setupModelRegistry(ModelLoader.java:150) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelManager.onResourceManagerReload(ModelManager.java:28) [ModelManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.registerReloadListener(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:121) [SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:560) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:422) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97) [start/:?]
    at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:25) [start/:?]
Caused by: net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition$MissingVariantException
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition.getVariant(ModelBlockDefinition.java:83) ~[ModelBlockDefinition.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader$VariantLoader.loadModel(ModelLoader.java:1175) ~[ModelLoader$VariantLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoaderRegistry.getModel(ModelLoaderRegistry.java:157) ~[ModelLoaderRegistry.class:?]
    ... 21 more
```

I have other blocks with similar naming conventions that work fine but are all the same texture on all sides.

The block in game shows the states "burn" and "facing" correctly but no texture is shown.

Comment: Please include the complete error in your question, MissingVariantException has multiple underlying causes, all of which are found below its stack trace beginning with `Caused By`. Additionally, [Code Style issue #4](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/61757-common-issues-and-recommendations/?do=findComment&comment=289567), [Problematic Code #4, #10](https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/61757-common-issues-and-recommendations/?do=findComment&comment=289566). `if(active)...else`: remove these 4 lines, do `.withProperty(BURNING, active)` instead. Not that you call `setState` any way

Comment: Thanks for the stack trace, unfortunately there's either more needed or there's an issue that is harder to diagnose based on your question. The reason it "has no texture" is because the model failed to load. There is no situation in which the model will fail *and* the game will show the correct texture. If you post your code as a working git repo it may be easier to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out and took pulling your code into a working project and seeing what happened. As I suspected there was a portion of the error you had not included, but I (upon seeing this myself) didn't know that it would throw the *real* error only once and then an unhelpful MissingVariantException for *every other variant* (and you grabbed the last one, not the first one, and in my prior experience they were all the same) so I didn't know what to tell you to look for (but now I know what happens in this situation).

Here's the originating error in full:

```
[09:01:45] [main/ERROR] [FML]: Exception loading blockstate for the variant harderfarming:c_furnace#burn=true,facing=west: 
java.lang.Exception: Could not load model definition for variant harderfarming:c_furnace
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.getModelBlockDefinition(ModelLoader.java:266) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadBlock(ModelBakery.java:121) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.loadBlocks(ModelLoader.java:221) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.setupModelRegistry(ModelLoader.java:159) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelManager.onResourceManagerReload(ModelManager.java:28) [ModelManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.resources.SimpleReloadableResourceManager.registerReloadListener(SimpleReloadableResourceManager.java:121) [SimpleReloadableResourceManager.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:554) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:416) [Minecraft.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118) [Main.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97) [start/:?]
    at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:25) [start/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Encountered an exception when loading model definition of 'harderfarming:c_furnace' from: 'harderfarming:blockstates/c_furnace.json' in resourcepack: 'FMLFileResourcePack:HardFarming'
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadModelBlockDefinition(ModelBakery.java:246) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadMultipartMBD(ModelBakery.java:223) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.getModelBlockDefinition(ModelBakery.java:208) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.getModelBlockDefinition(ModelLoader.java:262) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Neither 'variants' nor 'multipart' found
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition$Deserializer.deserialize(ModelBlockDefinition.java:155) ~[ModelBlockDefinition$Deserializer.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition$Deserializer.deserialize(ModelBlockDefinition.java:140) ~[ModelBlockDefinition$Deserializer.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:69) ~[TreeTypeAdapter.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887) ~[Gson.class:?]
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:825) ~[Gson.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.BlockStateLoader.load(BlockStateLoader.java:108) ~[BlockStateLoader.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBlockDefinition.parseFromReader(ModelBlockDefinition.java:42) ~[ModelBlockDefinition.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadModelBlockDefinition(ModelBakery.java:242) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.loadMultipartMBD(ModelBakery.java:223) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.renderer.block.model.ModelBakery.getModelBlockDefinition(ModelBakery.java:208) ~[ModelBakery.class:?]
    at net.minecraftforge.client.model.ModelLoader.getModelBlockDefinition(ModelLoader.java:262) ~[ModelLoader.class:?]
    ... 20 more
```

I used my existing mod ID of course, but the important part here is about half way down:

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Neither 'variants' nor 'multipart' found
```

Your blockstate file is wrong, you have a `"variant"` property when you should have `"variants"` with an S.

My advice going forward is "learn to read your error log" because they often tell you what's wrong, where, and how. In this case that advice applies by *starting at the top and working down,* as one error often causes another, and by fixing the first you resolve a whole bunch at once.