# Minecraft Fabric Modding (model problems)

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I'm new to modding and I have been trying to add blocks to Minecraft 1.17.1 that I feel are missing. I've had problems before that I solved after a while but this one has had me stumped for a couple days now.

As you can see, my item block models are working just fine along with any cube_all block models. Cube_column models however, are not being registered.

[Game Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyADh.png)

Here is my blockstates file along with their models. Maybe you can see the obvious mistake that I can't appear to find.

**Blockstates**

```
{
  "variants": {
    "axis=x": {
      "model": "expansion:block/stone_pillar_horizontal",
      "x": 90,
      "y": 90
    },
    "axis=y": {
      "model": "expansion:block/stone_pillar"
    },
    "axis=z": {
      "model": "expansion:block/stone_pillar_horizontal",
      "x": 90
    }
  }
}
```

**Model**

```
{
  "parent": "minecraft:block/cube_column",
  "textures": {
    "end": "expansion:blocks/stone_pillar_top",
    "side": "expansion:blocks/stone_pillar"
  }
}
```

**Horizontal Model**

```
{
  "parent": "minecraft:block/cube_column_horizontal",
  "textures": {
    "end": "expansion:blocks/stone_pillar_top",
    "side": "expansion:blocks/stone_pillar"
  }
}
```

Here is also the terminal message I receive when launching the mod. As you can see, the program for some reason takes issue with 'axis' and claims that my models are missing.

```
[Worker-Main-11/WARN] (Minecraft) Exception loading blockstate definition: 'expansion:blockstates/stone_pillar.json' in resourcepack: 'Expansion' for variant: 'axis=z': Unknown blockstate property: 'axis'
[Worker-Main-11/WARN] (Minecraft) Exception loading blockstate definition: 'expansion:blockstates/stone_pillar.json' in resourcepack: 'Expansion' for variant: 'axis=x': Unknown blockstate property: 'axis'
[Worker-Main-11/WARN] (Minecraft) Exception loading blockstate definition: 'expansion:blockstates/stone_pillar.json' in resourcepack: 'Expansion' for variant: 'axis=y': Unknown blockstate property: 'axis'
[Worker-Main-11/WARN] (Minecraft) Exception loading blockstate definition: 'expansion:blockstates/stone_pillar.json' missing model for variant: 'expansion:stone_pillar#'
```

I have double and triple checked that all of my files are where they should be, that there are no simple spelling mistakes and that nothing was left untied. IntelliJ also says that all my work has no flaws that it can tell. Please help me because I can't find it anywhere else :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception loading model for varian \[block\] for blockstate \[state\] MissingVariantException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58295582/exception-loading-model-for-varian-block-for-blockstate-state-missingvariant)